# Set text in <textarea>, including newlines

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set the text in a `<textarea>` from a js-function; I'm simply setting the `innerText`-attribute to a new value. The text is multiline and should be displayed as such. However, newlines are dropped by the browser and the entire text is displayed as one line:

```js
document.getElementById("my_textarea1").innerText = "foo\nbar"; // displayed as "foobar"

document.getElementById("my_textarea2").innerText = "foo\
    bar"; // displayed as "foobar"

document.getElementById("my_textarea3").innerText = `foo\
    bar`; // again, "foobar"
```

```html
<textarea id="my_textarea1"></textarea>
<textarea id="my_textarea2"></textarea>
<textarea id="my_textarea3"></textarea>
```

Is there a way to preserve newlines when setting the text in a `<textarea>`?

Comment: The point is that the newlines are coming from js-code, not the HTML itself.

Comment: I don't know why it is not working at your side but it is perfectly fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/jt42sL8e/5/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it. I use property "value" or "innerHTML" or "textContent":

```js
var area = document.getElementById("my_textarea");
area.value = "foo\nbar";

var area_2 = document.getElementById("my_textarea_2");
area_2.innerHTML = "foo\nbar";

var area_3 = document.getElementById("my_textarea_3");
area_3.textContent = "foo\nbar";
```

```html
<textarea id="my_textarea"></textarea>
<textarea id="my_textarea_2"></textarea>
<textarea id="my_textarea_3"></textarea>
```

Comment: @Luca It's different because you're using `innerText`, here has been used `innerHTML` and `value`; read carefully the answer before commenting and read the new [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct)

Comment: innerText not support "\n"

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `value` of the textarea, this works with `\n`, and

```
`foo\
bar`;
```

```js
document.querySelector("#my_textarea").value = "foo\nbar"
```

```html
<textarea id="my_textarea"></textarea>
```

If that doesn't work for you, use the `innerHTML` property, the same way:

```js
document.querySelector("#my_textarea").innerHTML = "foo\nbar"
```

```html
<textarea id="my_textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: It seems that < textarea > does not support the value attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: It shouldn't, yet it seems to do it :/

Answer (score 0):

Use area.innerHTML instead, innerText property strips off the new line character

```js
var area = document.getElementById("my_textarea");
area.innerHTML = "foo\nbar";
```

```html
<textarea id="my_textarea">

</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\r`  or `\n` for this.
Additionally HTML also supports `\t` to apply tab between two words.

```js
document.querySelector("#my_textarea1").value = "foo\rbar"

document.querySelector("#my_textarea2").value = "foo\nbar"

document.querySelector("#my_textarea3").value = "foo\tbar"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>New line using "\r" :</p>
<textarea id="my_textarea1"></textarea>
<br>
<p>New line using "\n" :</p>
<textarea id="my_textarea2"></textarea>
<br>
<p>Tab between tow words using "\t" :</p>
<textarea id="my_textarea3"></textarea>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTML Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-innertext):

> `element . innerText [ = value ]`
>
> Returns the element's text content "as rendered".
>
> Can be set, to replace the element's children with the given value, but with line breaks converted to `br` elements.

---

Meaning, what you have should have worked.  As noted by other answers you could use `textContent`, `value`, `innerHTML` all of which are more likely to work.

If you are set on using `textContent`, you have a few options/peculiarities, which I'll list out below:

1. Use an ES6 transpiler such as Babel.js
   You can test by enabling ES6 in Stack Overflow's snippet editor.
2. Refer to (3) options in the snippet below
   Note: these seem to work in OSX Safari but not Google Chrome

```js
// Call toString() method
document.getElementById('my_textarea').innerText = "foo\nbar".toString();

// Include the line return character
document.getElementById('my_textarea2').innerText = "foo\r\nbar";

// Apparently, any whitespace or escape character will work
document.getElementById('my_textarea3').innerText = "foo \nbar";
```

```html
<textarea id="my_textarea"></textarea>
<textarea id="my_textarea2"></textarea>
<textarea id="my_textarea3"></textarea>
```